# How to make documents upload using AJAX with progress Bar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to make an upload page for my site so that documents get uploaded asynchronously, I tried using AJAX, but AJAX has a limited access to the users filesystem, and when the information is sent to the server only the file name appears without the directory, I would like suggestion on how to do this easily without using JQuery, and also I would like to know if there is a way to monitor the progress of a file upload, so that I could add a progress bar to my site.

```
function createXMLHttpRequestObject(){
var xmlHttp     =   3;

if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
        //test for new version of internet Explorer
        xmlHttp     =   new ActiveXObject("Msxml.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e){
        try{
            xmlHttp     =   new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp =   2;
        }
    }
}

else{
    try{
        xmlHttp =   new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e){
        xmlHttp =   1;
    }

}

if(!xmlHttp){
    alert("Error creating Objece");
}
else{
    var xHttpArr = new Array();
    xHttpArr.push(xmlHttp);
    var i = xHttpArr.length - 1;
    return xHttpArr[i];
}
}

function process(xmlHttp, i){
if(xmlHttp.readyState   == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState  == 0){
    //value =   encodeURIComponent( objRef.value );

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "php/AjaxBody.php?value="+i, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange  =   handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
else{
    alert("Hold on");
}
}



function handleServerResponse(){

if(test.readyState == 1 || test.readyState == 2 || test.readyState == 3){

}

if (test.readyState == 4){
    if(test.status == 200){
        txtResponse =   test.responseText;
        bodyDiv =   document.getElementById("body");
        bodyDiv.innerHTML   =   txtResponse;

    }
    else{
        alert("Error with the xmlHttp status");
    }
}
/*
else{
    alert("Error with the xmlHttp readystate: " + x.status);
} */
}
```

Above is the code that creates the Object

```
    button.onclick = function() {
    send = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
    frmUpload = document.getElementById("frmUpload");
    file = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    processSending(send, frmUpload);
}
```

Above when the process method is called to send the file,
on the server I try to echo the file path, only the the name appears, like this

```
<?php
echo $_GET['value'];
?>
```

Comment: You say you tried something, yet you post zero code.

Comment: it is regular AJAX, Nothing Much, come on, that point meant a lot to me

Comment: Edit your question following the guidelines in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Why can't you use a jQuery plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are doing your file upload wrong. File uploads require you to do a proper POST request using forms as it requires the `enctype` form attribute to be `multipart/form-data`. Why? The browser sends the binary file data through the POST request and does the hard work of encoding the data correctly through the POST request to be read on the server. Any other way and you will just be getting the file name at the server (you can verify this with a tool like Fiddler).

Alright, then how do you do a file upload using AJAX? AFAIK it's not possible to read the user's file system directly (I think `FileReader` only allows reading through the sandboxed file system through the browser but I may be wrong here), so IMO there are 2 ways to go here:

- Using a hidden iframe approach for the file upload. Google it you will find lots of info it.
- Use a Flash based uploader. More on this at the end.

As far as getting the *location* of the file on the users file system using Javascript goes, forget about it. It's considered a security concern and many browsers only return the file name on reading the element value when using the HTML input file tag. (Unless you are thinking of using a flash component. More on that in the last point.)

Now coming to the progress bar issue. When your PHP script is actually run the entire file has already been uploaded to the server. So how to show a progress bar? A few (hackish) ways:

- An old school approach is to create a CGI script on the server to handle the upload. The advantage? CGI scripts can be run *during* the upload allowing you to retrieve the actual byte level progress of the upload. But this also requires you to update the progress at some place on the server which you can poll (with a separate AJAX request) and show in the browser to the user.
- Another most commonly used approach is using a flash based uploader (please don't kill me StackOverflow community). Yes it's still used by big names (I am looking at you Facebook). The advantage you will have is that you don't need any special scripts on the server. The Flash based client is fully aware of the number of bytes uploaded. Also you *may* have access to the actual file path string (note the use of *may* and *string*) which is not so openly possible with plain JS and HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `FileReader` and read the file into an `ArrayBuffer` or a `BinaryString` and then use multiple requests to send for example 1 mb sized packages. The receiving php script would then have to 'rebuild' the file by appending each received part to it. This would also solve the problem of echoing the file path on the server as you can (and have to) decide where to save it before writing to it.

Comment: You do not need to use FileReader to split files or blobs into pieces.  Simply use the slice function.

Comment: @RayNicholus Yeah, but you need the FileReader to read the file.

Comment: Read the file from where?  The OP hasn't specified that reading a file is required.  For all we know, the OP has an app that allows users to select a file from their filesystem which he then wants to upload.  This is the most likely scenario, and does not require use of FileReader.

Comment: Wow! Sorry... Didn't know these things existed! :)

Comment: @Ray Nicholus But how do you want to upload a file without reading it?

Comment: @jangxx Why do you need to read it client side?  What purpose does this serve?  Simple take the `File`, attach to a `FormData`  object, and send the `FormData` object via an XHR2 POST request.  If you want to split up the `File` into pieces, call the `slice` method on the `File`, which will return a `Blob`.  Attach the `Blob` to the `FormData`, send the `FormData`.  Using FileReader is unnecessary.

Comment: But how do you want to track the upload progress then? That's what he asked for. If you let the browser do the uploading you can't get this information.

Comment: @jangxx Sure you can.  You should familiarize yourself with XMLHttpRequest.  Here's the relevant section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that functionality. Thanks for the info, but that doesn't make my answer wrong. You _could_ do it with a `FileReader`.

Comment: Yes, you could, if you wanted to be horribly inefficient about it and take a completely unnecessary approach.